# "Global" hotkey EXCEPT in text entry

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm working on a large application with a lot of different windows/frames/panes/tabs, many of which may be open at any time. Requirements call for some hotkeys that give focus to a certain tab in a certain window. I would like to avoid registering a KeyListener with every single window/component that might have focus; as such, I tried the following

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher(){
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyChar() == '-'){
                doTheThing();
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

That first "return false" allows that character to go through to other possible consumers, such as text entry fields. The problem is that the code still fires, and will jerk the user back to the tab in question (potentially pulling them away from what they were doing, if it was another tab in the same window.)

Is there a way to have this code fired globally, EXCEPT if it would otherwise enter into a text panel? (Maybe a way to add a handler that would get it "last" rather than "first" - so it only fires if nothing else is consuming the event?)

I'm pretty new to UI design, so apologies if this is a dumb question, and thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`KeyboardFocusManager#getFocusOwner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#getFocusOwner--) and determine if it's a `JTextComponent` or not...

```
if (!(KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner() instanceof JTextComponent)) {
    //...
}
```

or some such

Comment: Huh... does that mean that the FocusManager is the same as the thing that has focus? And does that also mean that it's passing around the added KeyEventDispatchers, cause those seem to fire even when different things are in focus...

Comment: Opps, forgot to add `getFocusOwner` :P

Comment: Okay, that makes much more sense, and seems to work. Thanks!